# Passing c string into function

Tags: c, string

I have a question regarding passing c string into function.

If I have a function:

```
void reverse(char* c){
   //here is the reverse code
}
```

In the main:

```
int main(){
   char* c1="abcd";
   char c2[5]="abcd";
   char * c3=new char[5];
   c3="abcd";
}
```

In my test, only c1 is not allow to pass into the function, other two works fine. I would like to know why c1 is a wrong usage?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Precisely why you should only ever use `const char *` for pointers to string literals.

Comment: `new char[5]` is C++; it's a syntax error in C.

Comment: Saying it's not allowed doesn't tell us anything. What actually happened when you tried? A compiler error? A run-time error? With what message? The `reverse` function you've shown us does nothing, and you haven't shown us a call to it. Read this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: not only that you are leaking that memory when he reassighns c3 to point to a const string literal insted of the memory he created with new (or even if he corrects that to be using malloc)

Comment: would have been helpful if you showed yourself actually calling the function in main otherwise reverse function doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is C++, not C; `new char[5]` is a syntax error in C.

C and C++ are two different languages.  In C++, string literals are `const`, and passing a string literal to a function that takes a `char*` argument is an error. You should have gotten an error message (which you haven't bothered to show us) from your C++ compiler.

(If you were using a C compiler, it would have accepted a call like `reverse("foo")`, but it would have complained about the `new char[5]`.)

Comment: @dianedan: You're welcome. For the benefit of future readers, please update your question to show the exact error message you got (copy-and-paste it, don't re-type it), and change the "c" tag to "c++" if you're compiling code as C++.

Answer (score 1):

`c1` will point to a string literal and attempting to modify a string literal is undefined behavior, this is based on the assumption that `reverse` will attempt to reverse the string in place.